# How to remove a mod_rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Today, I try to redirect in my web using Mod_rewrite. But I do something wrong with it and I want to fix the rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8067/$1 [R=301]
```

I want to change the rule to something else. But when I delete rule in .htaccess and restart apache. The rule still affect to url. I try to delete .htaccess file but the problem still occur.

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I decided to open my web page on other computer and get no error. So I clear my browser data and the problem is solved.

Hope this help!!